# how I can translate changes made in Cheat Engine into my game.exe

Tags: memory, cheat-engine

I have a game I am looking to modify a bit by altering the exe code, something I have a little bit of experience with (low level hacking HEX only as I do not have source code of game).

I found a trainer that writes into the game.exe memory to do things like increase health, money etc. The trainer itself can do many things, one of which is preventing enemies from dropping loot once they are killed. This is the function that I wish to embed in the game.exe.

I have found the address of this function in Cheat Engine and have successfully written new data into memory to prevent the look drops. Now my task is how to make this permanent in the game.exe?

Does anyone know how I can translate the changes I make in Cheat Engine into my game.exe so that I no longer need a trainer to make the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheat engine does not, as far as I'm aware, have the capability to permanently patch the .exe file. To do this you will want to use [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) which does allow it.

You have already found the address's you need in CE and you can use these in OllyDbg to go right to where you need to change stuff.